# R Shiny actionButton to trim data limits

Tags: r, shiny, trim

I am writing a R Shiny script to remove bad data points by clicking on the graph.  The flow goes like this:

Objective #1: The user clicks actionButton "Delete below", then clicks a point on the graph.  This point is the ymin, and R removes any y values less than that.  "Remove" = declares to be NA.

Objective #2: Conversely, user clicks actionButton "Delete above", then clicks a point on the graph.  This point is the ymax, and R removes any y values greater than that.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
library(shiny)
x = seq(0,10,length=50)
y = sin(x)
picked.style = "color: white; background-color: black"

ui = fluidPage(
  plotOutput("y.trimmed", click = "plot_click"),
  actionButton(inputId="b.above.pushed", label="Delete Above"),
  actionButton(inputId="b.below.pushed", label="Delete Below")
)

server = function(input, output) {
  v <- reactiveValues(
    ymin = min( y, na.rm=T),
    ymax = max(y, na.rm=T),
    pick.bottun = "none"
  )

  ############ push a button  
  # pick above
  observeEvent(input$b.above.pushed, {
    v$pick.bottun <- "above"
    observeEvent(input$plot_click, 
    {v$ymax = input$plot_click$y}, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  })
  # pick below
  observeEvent(input$b.below.pushed, {
    v$pick.bottun <- "below"
    observeEvent(input$plot_click, 
    { v$ymin <- input$plot_click$y}, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  })

  ############# update and replot data
  output$y.trimmed <- renderPlot({
    # clean data
    print(paste("ymin=",round(v$ymin), "ymax=",round(v$ymax)) )
    cc = y <= v$ymin & is.na(y)==F; y[cc] = NA
    cc = y >= v$ymax & is.na(y)==F; y[cc] = NA
    plot(x, y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thus far it works fine for Objective #1 if that's all you run (even if you run it multiple times).  Likewise it works fine for Objective #2.

The problem occurs if you want to declare a ymin and then declare a ymax.  It will declare a min just fine (hypothetically let's say ymin=0.1), but then why you go to declare a ymax (hypothetically ymax=0.5), it sets BOTH ymin and ymax equal to 0.5.  This then deletes all the data, causing the code to crash.  The same thing happens if you declare ymax first and then try to set ymin.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think this would be much easier to solve with a radioButton or selectInput rather then two actionButtons would that be acceptable as well?

Comment: Thanks so much everyone!  I actually adopted both approaches (as each is useful in my app).

Comment: If you found the answers helpful. please accept them and/or upvote them. This makes it easier for future readers to find what they are looking for.

Comment: Ok.  How do I do that?  (I'm new to actually participating on this site, though I've used answers here for years).

Comment: Hi, you can read about accepting answers here
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to put observeEvent in another. You are better off always placing them clean in the server function and the let them react to according to the what values have been previusly chosen. Like this.

```
library(shiny)
x = seq(0,10,length=50)
y = sin(x)
picked.style = "color: white; background-color: black"

ui = fluidPage(
  plotOutput("y.trimmed", click = "plot_click"),
  actionButton(inputId="b.above.pushed", label="Delete Above"),
  actionButton(inputId="b.below.pushed", label="Delete Below")
)

server = function(input, output) {
  v <- reactiveValues(
    ymin = min( y, na.rm=T),
    ymax = max(y, na.rm=T),
    pick.bottun = "none"
  )

  ############ push a button  
  # pick above
  observeEvent(input$b.above.pushed, {
    v$pick.bottun <- "above"
  })

  observeEvent(input$plot_click, 
               {
                 if(v$pick.bottun == "above"){
                    v$ymax = input$plot_click$y
                 } else if(v$pick.bottun == "below"){
                   v$ymin = input$plot_click$y
                 }

               }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  # pick below
  observeEvent(input$b.below.pushed, {
    v$pick.bottun <- "below"
  })

  ############# update and replot data
  output$y.trimmed <- renderPlot({
    # clean data
    print(paste("ymin=",round(v$ymin), "ymax=",round(v$ymax)) )
    cc = y <= v$ymin & is.na(y)==F; y[cc] = NA
    cc = y >= v$ymax & is.na(y)==F; y[cc] = NA
    plot(x, y)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!